# Prefech many to many relation for one class instance

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm

I want to limit the queries for a detail view. I want to access multiple many to many fields for one class instance in less query. It seems [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) doesn't work with `get` and the server hits he database for every manytomany field.

`JobInstance = Job.objects.get(pk=id).prefetch_related('cities').prefetch_related('experience_level')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* let it work, by reordering it, like:

```
job_instance = Job.objects.prefetch_related('cities', 'experience_level').get(pk=id)
```

A `.prefetch_related(..)` is defined on a `QuerySet`, when you perform a `.get(..)` then you fetch the object, and you are no longer working with a queryset.

But for a single object, `.prefetch_related(..)` will **not** improve efficiency. After all, `.prefetch_related(..)` will make here two extra queries to fetch the related objects, exactly as much as not prefetching, and later evaluating the related objects of the `job_instance`.

`.prefetch_related(..)` is therefore useful when you want to fetch the related objects of *multiple* objects in bulk.

Comment: when using prefetch_related it actually hits database one more time. It's better to call the function of the class instance that returns the data.

Comment: @csandreas1: well both the `prefetch_related` and the `job_instance.cities.all()` (without such prefetch) will result in extra queries, therefore, as said you do not "gain" . `.select_related(..)` will "piggyback" on the query to fetch the object, but you can not use that for a one-to-many relation, or a many-to-many relation, since that could generate a huge amount of duplicate records.

Comment: It actually has a gain! When using multiple times the template tag with the associated data, i doesn't hit the database

Comment: @csandreas1: well if you store `job_instance.cities.all()` somewhere, it will not hit the database a second time either. The reason it makes multiple hits is because if you define `job_instance.cities.all()` you make a copy of the old queryset, without its caching behavior.